# Number of batches in Salesforce.com Batch Jobs

Tags: schedulebatch

I have a batch job when it gets executed. Number of batches is shown as = 2. Ideally it should be run in 1 batch only. because of 2 batches duplicate actions are being performed. Is it a Salesforce.com defect. How can we ensure that actions should get performed only once and number of batches should be always equal = 1

Answer (score 1):

You will see that the [Database.executeBatch(batchClassObject, scope)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_executeBatch_2) documentations says:

> The value for scope must be greater than 0.
>
> If the start method of the batch class returns a
>   Database.QueryLocator, the scope parameter of Database.executeBatch
>   can have a maximum value of 2,000. If set to a higher value,
>   Salesforce chunks the records returned by the QueryLocator into
>   smaller batches of up to 200 records. If the start method of the batch
>   class returns an iterable, the scope parameter value has no upper
>   limit; however, if you use a very high number, you may run into other
>   limits.

So if you are using a `QueryLocator` and you have 2,000 or less rows, set the scope to 2,000 and only one batch will result.

It sounds like what you are doing isn't a good match for a Batchable as that is primarily designed to break work up into *multiple* separate transactions.

Comment: Number of records in a batch are less than 10 still 2 batches are getting processed.

Comment: @ABHIJIT Surprising. Suggest you add `System.debug('>>> scope=' + scope);` calls in the execute to try to see what is going on.

Comment: Problem is resolved after reducing scope to 1 record

Comment: @ABHIJIT Sorry for the bad advice there.